# How do I create a batch script that copies the contents based on filename with date?

Tags: date, batch-file, copy

I am in the process of creating a batch script that can copy files from a specific folder to another folder. An empty text file with the file name of the current date is also created in this destination folder.

How can I make it so that the batch script notes the date of this text file and then copies from the folder only the files that are not older than this date to the destination folder?

This is how the batch script looks at the moment:

```
@echo off
ROBOCOPY "C:\StartDirectory\" "C:\Destination\" /S /MAXAGE:
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set today=!date:/=-!
set now=!time::=-!
set millis=!now:*.=!
set now=!now:.%millis%=!

echo Textfilecontent > BUILDDATE_!today!_!now!.txt
move BUILDDATE_!today!_!now!.txt "C:\Destination\"
```

Alternatively, it would also work for me if the batch script simply ignored the unchanged files from the start folder and destination folder when copying and only copies the changed files.

Comment: In your `ROBOCOPY` command line, you need to change `"C:\StartDirectory\"` and `"C:\Destination\"` to `"C:\StartDirectory"` and `"C:\Destination"` respectively. The trailing backward slashes are escaping the doublequotes. I have no idea why you're using `MAXAGE:` with no age, and you are `echo`ing a trailing space too!

Comment: Thank you! Yes the /d command solved my isse!